# error with url helper, $this->url(array(), 'home'); generate a link like this http///home

Tags: zend-framework, url-helper

error with url helper, $this->url(array(), 'home'); generate a link like this http///home

Hi,

I've create a custom route in my application.ini file like this:

*resources.router.routes.home.route = /home

resources.router.routes.home.defaults.module = default 

resources.router.routes.home.defaults.controller = index

resources.router.routes.home.defaults.action = index*

and in my master layout I want to write a link to my the home page like this

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array(), 'home'); ?>">Home</a>
```

but I got in the generated html file, 
`http///home`, 
can someone help me to get the url in this form `/home`, or `http//example.com/home`, ?
Thanks

Comment: What happens if you use just resources.router.routes.home.route = home (with no slash)?

Comment: what is your baseUrl() setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->baseUrl('/home');
```

should work

Comment: It is ok I have a mistake in my resource definition